# Magento Locale/Timezone Issue

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, locale, magento-1.9.1

I recently upgraded from Magento 1.5 to 1.9 and I have noticed some odd behavior with dates/times.  I can't say I payed much attention to this prior to the upgrade, so I'm going to try to go back and test this on 1.5 to confirm it didn't happen.  So far I have tested this on our live production website, my local dev copy of our site, and a clean Magento CE 1.9.1.0 that has no customizations at all, and I get the same results every time.  The problem I'm seeing is that, in some cases, the customer "Created at" time gets buggered such that the Month and Day values get swapped.  The steps to reliably reproduce are:

1. Place an order on the frontend, using the option to save your account for later use
2. Go into the admin and view the customer's account.  Take note of the "Created at" time.  Today, for instance, it would say Apr 2, 2015.
3. From the admin, create a new order for the same customer.
4. After placing the order, go back to the customer's account and look at the "Created at" time.  Note that it has changed to "Feb 4, 2015".
5. Repeat steps 3-4 and note that it has changed the "Created at" back to "Apr 2, 2015"

As I said, this happens for me on 2 different servers in both our website code and a clean 1.9.1.0 install, which leads me to believe it is a bug in the code and not a configuration issue, but I'm not 100% sure.  Timezones, locales, and such can get a little confusing, so I might have something wrong in the setup.  If you have any ideas or can/cannot reproduce this, please share your findings/thoughts.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your Locale options correctly?

```
System > Configuration > GENERAL > General > Locale Options (3rd Option)
```

Comment: I re-read your post, April 2, 2015 would, in american date format be written 4/2/2015 ... Which is the 4th of february 2015 in european format. So that's your starting point!

Answer (score 0):

I also bumped into the same problem. The answer to this problem is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months?lq=1

If you don't have $this->_getFormat() function in your file. See here:
https://gist.github.com/ihor-sviziev/e96064240d167457709e

Remember to refresh your cache.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, then, you have the following issues:

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order` is subclassed and is providing a concrete `getCreatedAt` method (as opposed to the method being magic)

Your data stored in the `created_at` column for the order in question actually has a Unix timestamp or some other data? This may hint at an illegal schema change.
To test if the model is subclassed, echo out `get_class($order)` - remove the rewrite if the model has been rewritten to diagnose.

Comment: You missed the point entirely.  I'm not trying to use date/time functions in some custom code, I'm talking about core functionality.  You place an order in the admin and the customer's "Created at" time gets messed up.  That's the problem I'm trying to track down.

Comment: I see.  my bad.  ok.  are you using a custom theme by chance for both sites?  If are are running the same "error" on both servers it would be an assumption that yes perhaps there is a bug in the theme code you have.  If this is the case, i would contact the theme developer, because chances are others have noticed it too, and maybe have a proper solution.  If not.  Well I guess i have not been to helpful.

Comment: As I said in my OP, this is happening on a stock Magento 1.9.1 install, no customizations.  It only has the sample data and Madison Island store/theme.  I'd be surprised if something is broken in our theme that is also broken in the sample.  It doesn't seem to be theme related, it's not due to any 3rd party extensions, and it's happening on 2 completely different servers, one of which I didn't even configure so I couldn't have made the same mistake twice.  It really smells like a core bug.  By any chance, did you actually go and try the steps I provided to see if it happens for you?

Comment: I'll double check, but I'm pretty sure I checked that already and there's nothing overriding the getCreatedAt method.  Since it's happening on a clean install, that wouldn't likely be the case anyhow.

Comment: I did try, and was unable to reproduce, am going to take another look at it